# Android | Send "extras" to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

In my app, I download some file with

```
        DownloadManager downloadManagerStore = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(queryURL);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dir);
        downloadManagerStore.enqueue(request);
```

And I manage the file with a `BroadcastReceiver`, this is the code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    //do something
}
```

But I do two different download and when they finish the `BroadcastReceiver` run, but how can I know which download is finish?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your download id  in preferences(most preferably) or anywhere when you `enqueue()` your download request -

```
long downloadId = downloadManagerStore.enqueue(request);
```

And then in your receiver, when download gets completed you can match your saved `downloadId` with the `DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID` as below -

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;            

          String action = intent.getAction();
          if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                  long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                 //Check your saved "downloadId" with "id" and perform your task depending on that
          }    
}
```